# How would you construct a for loop that finds the sum of the first index of each of theses arrays

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
        static final int[] HotDogdb = {30, 45, 44, 37,51};
    static final int[] ToastedChickendb = {25, 30, 45, 15,33};
    static final int[] ToastedSteakdb = {10, 15, 12, 16,17};
    static final int[] ToastedEggTdb = {14, 12, 17, 20,16};
    static final int[] ToastedSteakEdb ={5, 8, 3, 8,6};
    static final int[] ChickenRolldb = {27, 28, 23,20,21};
    static final int[] SteakRolldb = {19, 22, 23, 21,18};
    static final int[] EggTomatodb = {15, 16,10, 12,11};
    static final int[] CheeseTomatodb = {18, 19, 22, 21,20};
    static final int[] SteakEggdb = {10, 16, 13, 17,15};
    static final int[] tCheeseTomatodb = {23, 30, 27, 40,37};
    static final int[][] sales = new int[][] { HotDogdb, ToastedChickendb, ToastedSteakdb, ToastedEggTdb, ToastedSteakEdb,ChickenRolldb,SteakRolldb,EggTomatodb,CheeseTomatodb, SteakEggdb, tCheeseTomatodb };
```

So basically finding the sum of index @ 0  all the way through 
what ive got so far

```
int total8 = 0;
int i;


for (i=0; i <= 11; i++){
total8 = total8 +  MyConstants.sales[i][0];}
                                jTextArea6.setText(""+total8);
```

Comment: It's the classic `off by one` error. Instead of `<= 11` use `!= 11`, or better yet, use `sales.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `i <= 11`, use `i < 11`:

```
for (i=0; i < 11; i++) {
```

Otherwise, you'll get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, since `sales.length` is `11`, and you are using `i <= 11`, thus, your last iteration will try to access `sales[11]` which does not exist (note that arrays in Java are **0-indexed**).

Another option is to use `i < sales.length`. This way, if you add more elements to the array, you don't need to change the code of your `for`-loop:

```
for (i=0; i < sales.length; i++) {
```

Comment: or better yet - use the `length` field, or a for each loop.

Comment: @amit: Yes, I have that suggestion in my last paragraph. I'm gonna add an example, though, thanks.